# Gimp greyscaling an image

Tags: gimp, grayscale

I'm trying to greyscale an image in Gimp 2.10.12. I can't access the grey scale palette to greyscale the image.

Can anyone explain how I can greyscale in this version of Gimp?

Thanks.

Comment: Open an image in GIMP and in the menu along the top click *Image > Mode > Grayscale*

Answer (score 3):

To make your image grayscale you can use `Colors > Desaturate > Desaturate` (technically, your image is still RGB, with three color channels, but R=G=B).

You can also make it truly grayscale (one single channel), with `Image > Mode > Grayscale`. Note that this may make some filters unusable/disabled.

For the more adventurous, there is also `Colors > Desaturate > Color to Gray`. This requires patience or a good PC or both. Some interesting effects because it can do a poor man's tone-mapping.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Xenoid's answer, here are a few more methods.

- There's also *Colors > Desaturate > Mono Mixer* which allows you to adjust the channels, and to preserve luminosity
- Or with the [G'MIC plugin](https://gmic.eu/): the *Black and White > Black and White* filter, which
  has a bunch of options, especially good if you are looking for
  dramatic black and white conversions
- Also in G'MIC: *Colors > Simulate Film* - the black and white film presets
  are quite nice, plus extra controls to adjust/tweak manually.

You can always do *Image > Mode > Greyscale* afterwards if you need an actual greyscale image.

*Note: I have no affiliation with the G'MIC website/plugin developers.*